How to draw a line on a folium map when clicking a marker?
I'm working on a problem where I have a TimestampedGeojson which displays several markers, which move around over time.
I want to be able to click on a marker, and show the GPS coordinates associated with that line as a polyline on the map (to display the historical movement of the marker, basically).
I've already found the nice example here, but sadly that doesn't seem to work with the TimestampedGeojson markers (I don't know why). The map and markers appear, but the lines don't.
Here's some example code:
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson

data = {
    "time": ['2017-10-25 16:30:00', '2017-10-25 17:30:00', '2017-10-25 18:30:00',
             '2017-10-25 16:30:00', '2017-10-25 17:30:00', '2017-10-25 18:30:00',
             '2017-10-25 16:30:00', '2017-10-25 17:30:00', '2017-10-25 18:30:00'],
    "Lat": [45.5, 45.6, 45.7, 46.0, 46.1, 46.2, 46.5, 46.6, 46.7],
    "Lon": [4.5, 4.5, 4.6, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7],
    "id": ['marker1', 'marker1', 'marker1', 'marker2', 'marker2', 'marker2', 'marker3', 'marker3', 'marker3']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time']    = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

m = folium.Map(location=[df['Lat'].mean(), df['Lon'].mean()], zoom_start=9)

# Create the GeoJson features
features = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    
    features.append({
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [row['Lon'], row['Lat']],
        },
        'properties': {
            'time': row['time'].isoformat(),
            'tooltip':  f'{row.id}',         
               
            'popup': '', # On click, this is where I'd like to draw a line from the marker, to [45.912280, 6.112371]
            
        }
    })

geojson = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': features,
}

TimestampedGeoJson(
    geojson,
    period='PT1H',
    add_last_point=True,
    auto_play=False,
    loop=False,
).add_to(m)

m.save('map_with_lines.html')

Any help (or other way to achieve the same goal: drawing a line based on a marker click in TimestampedGeojson) would be appreciated!
